# StreamPlot of a square-root - Issue

Tags: plotting, vector-calculus

When I plot

```
r[x_, y_] := Sqrt[x^2 + y^2];
θ[x_, y_] := ArcTan[x, y];
a=3;

Q[k_, N_] := Module[{pts1}, pts1 = Table[{0, x}, {x, -2 N, 2 N, 0.5}];
StreamPlot[{-Cos[θ[x, y] k] a^(1/2)/r[x, y]^(
1/2) + (1 - Sin[θ[x, y] k]^2 a/r[x, y])^(1/2) + 
a^(1/2)/r[x, y]^(1/2) Cos[θ[x, y] k], 
a^(1/2)/r[x, y]^(1/2) Sin[θ[x, y] k]}, {x, -2 N, 
2 N}, {y, -2 N, 2 N}, PlotRange -> {Full, Full}, 
RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, x^2 + y^2 > a^2], 
StreamPoints -> {pts1, Automatic, Scaled[2]}, 
StreamStyle -> {Blue, Thick, "Line"}, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", 
StreamScale -> Full]
```

Mathematica doesn't give any output.

Whereas, if I put the Abs around the square root bit, plotting something similar to what is shown [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/73201/streamplot-segmented-lines) it works, even if I am not sure that those discontinuities in the gradients should appear (I mean the spikes near the x axes).

I report the code for the second case, the one that works, and the figure:

```
r[x_, y_] := Sqrt[x^2 + y^2];
θ[x_, y_] := ArcTan[x, y];
a = 3;
Q[k_, N_] := 
 Module[{pts1}, pts1 = Table[{0, x}, {x, -2 N, 2 N, 0.5}];
 StreamPlot[{-Cos[θ[x, y] k] a^(1/2)/r[x, y]^(1/2) + 
 Abs[(1 - Sin[θ[x, y] k]^2 a/r[x, y])]^(1/2) + 
 a^(1/2)/r[x, y]^(1/2) Cos[θ[x, y] k], 
 a^(1/2)/r[x, y]^(1/2) Sin[θ[x, y] k]}, {x, -2 N, 
 2 N}, {y, -2 N, 2 N}, PlotRange -> {Full, Full}, 
 RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, x^2 + y^2 > a^2], 
 StreamPoints -> {pts1, Automatic, Scaled[2]}, 
 StreamStyle -> {Blue, Thick, "Line"}, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality",
 StreamScale -> Full]]

 Q[1/2, 10]
```

[image]

What is wrong with that square root?

Comment: `RegionPlot[(1 - Sin[\[Theta][x, y]/2]^2 a/r[x, y]) < 0, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}]`

Comment: @belisarius That's not the problem, it's just that I am not expecting to see those points on the left of the empty circle.

Answer (score 2):

In order to examine the offending `Sqrt`, I added

```
EvaluationMonitor :> If[1 - Sin[θ[x, y] k]^2 a/r[x, y] < 0, 
  Print[x, "  ", y, "  ", r[x, y], "  ", θ[x, y], "  ", 1 - Sin[θ[x, y] k]^2 a/r[x, y]]]
```

to the first function `Q` in the Question.  Interestingly, numerous instances of `r[x, y] < a` were printed.  For instance

```
-2.27757  -1.41668  2.68223  -2.58514  -0.0341049
```

Of course, the `Sqrt` would produce complex numbers in those instances, and I imagine that `StreamPlot` could not cope with them when it began plotting.  Putting `Abs` around the argument of the `Sqrt`, as in the second definition of `Q`, eliminates this issue, of course.  To corroborate this assessment, I replaced

```
(1 - Sin[θ[x, y] k]^2 a/r[x, y])^(1/2)
```

by

```
(Max[1 - Sin[θ[x, y] k]^2 a/r[x, y], 0])^(1/2)
```

in the first definition of `Q`, and it then worked fine.

It is not obvious to me why `StreamPlot` computes and uses values outside the `RegionFunction`.  Perhaps, it needs them in order to construct accurate stream lines near the edges of the `RegionFunction`.

By the way, "those discontinuities in the gradients" are caused by the discontinuity in `Sin[θ[x, y] k]` for `k = 1/2` in

```
a^(1/2)/r[x, y]^(1/2) Sin[θ[x, y] k]
```

as can be seen from

```
Plot3D[a^(1/2)/r[x, y]^(1/2) Sin[θ[x, y] /2], {x, -20, 20}, {y, -20, 20}, 
 RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, x^2 + y^2 > a^2], PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: vy in 3D]

**Update: More Strange Behavior**

As an experiment, I changed the range of `StreamPlot` from `{x, -2 N, 2 N}, {y, -2 N, 2 N}` to `{x, -2 N, 2 N}, {y, 0, 2 N}`.  The first definition of `Q` then produced a plot, although not what one might have expected.

[image: restricted range]

Two aspects of this plot are striking.  Most streamlines end at `x = 0`, and streamlines also are plotted for `-2 < y < 0`.  (The arrow heads appear in all cases that I have run.  I use V 10.0.2.0.)  Using `EvaluationMonitor` as above showed that `StreamPlot` continued to evaluate the functions outside `RegionFunction`, and additionally for `y < 0`.

On the other hand, the change of range in the second definition  of `Q` produced the expected complete set of streamlines for `y > 0` but also produced streamlines for `-2 < y < 0`, just as in the plot above.